# Limit the value of a field according to another one

Tags: django, django-models

I need to make sure that if `attribute A` in model M has a certain value then `attribute B` won't be `None`.

for example:

```
M.A == True then M.B != None

M.A = False then M.B = anything (None, int..)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Model.clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean):

```
class M(models.Model):
    A = models.BooleanField()
    B = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def clean(self):
        if self.A and self.B is None:
            raise ValidationError("B can not be None lwhile A is None")
```

You will raise `ValidationError` in conditions that is not valid.